# optimizar consulta mysql ordenando por fecha

Tags: mysql

actualmente trabajo en un sistema de gestión de solicitudes, cada solicitud tiene varios estados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las solicitudes se filtran por estado según el mes obteniendo el ultimo estado que se le asigno a la solicitud, para ello se tiene esta consulta que obtiene el max estado de solicitud asi

```
SELECT * 
FROM estados_solicitudes 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT 
    MAX(id)FROM estados_solicitudes 
    GROUP BY csu_solicitud_id
)
```

alguno sabe como puedo optimizar la consulta ya que actualmente la aplicación tiene mas de 17.000 registros y esta tardando mucho, realmente lo que necesito es un reporte del ultimo estado por solicitud en determinada fecha
gracias

Comment: Si haces esta consulta `SELECT  MAX(id),csu_solicitud_id,parameter_id FROM estados_solicitudes GROUP BY csu_solicitud_id`, no te arroja lo que quieres?

Comment: arroja error 1055

Comment: Y qué índices tienen las tablas? 17k registros son muy pocos para tener problemas de desempeño

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener la última solicitud de cada csu_solicitud_id

```
SELECT csu_solicitud_id, MAX(id)
FROM estados_solicitudes
GROUP BY csu_solicitud_id
```

Si quieres los detalles de la solicitud, junto con los datos del último estado

```
SELECT a.*, c.*
FROM Csu_solicitudes a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT csu_solicitud_id, MAX(id) as MAXID
   FROM Estados_solicitudes
   GROUP BY csu_solicitud_id
) b on a.id = b.csu_solicitud_id
INNER JOIN Estados_solicitudes c on b.MaxID = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta no tiene aspecto de hacer nada ineficiente, te propongo crear un índice con el campo `csu_solicitud_id` para agilizar esa consulta intermedia de agrupamiento que realizas:

`ALTER TABLE estados_solicitudes ADD INDEX(csu_solicitud_id);`

Como los `id` entiendo que son claves principales, ya estarán indexados.

Comment: se soluciono agregando un indice, muchas gracias

Comment: @NicolasAldana si esta respuesta soluciono tu problema, recuerda aceptarla